# Using Cypher how would one select all nodes connected to a node within exactly one hop whilst excluding the central node from the result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image: Graph]

Take the above image as an example. Using Cypher, how would I match all of the nodes except for the longest chain and the central node? I.e. all nodes within exactly one hop of the central node whilst excluding the central node (all nodes and edges except 3 nodes and 2 edges).

I have tried the following:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = "123" MATCH path = (m)-[*1..1]->(n) RETURN m
```

This very nearly works, however it still returns the central node (i.e. node n). How would I exclude this node from my query result?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

This will return all distinct nodes directly connected to the specified node, and explicitly prevents the specified node from being returned (in case it has a relationship to itself):

```
MATCH (n:Node)--(m)
WHERE n.id = "123" AND n <> m
RETURN DISTINCT m;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, your suggested solution returns the exact same number of nodes as the query in my question. I am specifically looking for a query that excludes the central node from the result.

Comment: I have updated my answer to prevent `n` from being included in the result. I also ensure all returned nodes are distinct.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Your updated solution is something I tried myself before asking the question and for some reason it still returns that node even though there is an explicit statement to not return it. Very odd behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would have liked to match the nodes as mentioned in my question and delete them. However, as I have not found a way to do so an inverse approach can be utilised whereby all nodes but those as mentioned in the question are matched instead. Thereby effectively excluding (but not deleting) the unwanted nodes.

This can be achieved using this query:

```
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = "123" MATCH path = (m)-[*2..]->(n) RETURN path
```

This returns the central node and all paths to that node that have a "length" greater than or equal to 2.